# How to enable http2/grpc on port 80 (i.e. without TLS) with nginx ingress?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, grpc, http2, nginx-ingress

As per these two issues on `ingress-nginx` Github, it seems that the only way to get grpc/http2 working on port 80 without TLS is by using a custom config template:

1. [ingress does not supporting http2 at port 80 without tls #6313](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6313)
2. [Add new annotation to support listen 80 http2 #6736](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6736)

Unfortunately I could not find any straightforward examples on how to set-up a custom nginx-ingress config. Here are the links I tried:

1. [Custom NGINX template](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/)
2. [Custom Templates](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.11.1/examples/custom-templates)

Can anyone help me with the exact steps and config on how to get grpc/http2 working with nginx-ingress on port 80 **without TLS**?

Comment: This seem to me more complicated than having GRPC over TLS. Roughly the steps are: 1) launch a separate nginx controller in an empty namespace to avoid issues with the main controller; 2) create custom templates, using [these](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/v1.11.1/internal/configs/version1) as a reference; 3) put them in a `configMap` like [this](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.11.1/examples/custom-templates#example);

Comment: 4) Mount the templates into the controller pod as in this [example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/#custom-nginx-template)

Comment: Thanks @anemyte - you're right. This is more complicated than it should be!

Answer (score 2):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As already mentioned in the comments, the steps to make it work are as follows:

1. Launch a separate nginx controller in an empty namespace to avoid issues with the main controller.
2. Create custom templates, using [these](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.11.1/internal/configs/version1) as a reference.
3. Put them in a `ConfigMap` like [this](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.11.1/examples/custom-templates#example).
4. Mount the templates into the controller pod as in this [example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/#custom-nginx-template).